# Time complexity of recursive function that calls itself in a loop

Tags: recursion, math, time-complexity, big-o

Given the function

```
void function(n) 
{        
for (int i = n; i > 0; i = floor(i/2))
 {            
  function(floor(i/2));
 }               
}
```

I'm having a hard time finding time complexity of this type of function. Chatgpt says it is *log(n)* but I believe it has to be greater. How to write the recurrence equation or what is the correct approach to solving this?

---

More examples: [https://stackoverflow.com/q/76959413/17253572]

Comment: As the code is currently written (and without an exact specification what `/=` actually does) this function may never even terminate. Ie, `i` may never reach `0`, because there is no number `x > 0` such that `x/2 == 0`

Comment: It halfs its value each iteration

Comment: Well yes, but as I said: If you have any number `x` that is greater than `0`, `x/2` will never be `0` ... Because if that was the case, there would also be a number `y = 2 * 0` where `y != 0` . And I hope, we agree that such a `y` doesn't exist ...

Comment: I know what you probably mean, ie `i /= 2` is performing an *integer division*, ie `floor(i/2)` But as you are in the field of theorectical computer science here, you have to be exact. And if you implement this algorithm in any programming language, it depends on the language and the types involved what `/=` (or more generally `/`) actually does. For instance Javascript *won't*  do an integer division and `1/2` will result in `0.5` , then `0.25`, `0.125` and so on and so forth, but never reach `0`

Comment: yes that is  what i mean. Lets say this is not  in Javascript

Comment: regarding chatGPT as a congenital liar won't get you wrong in 99.9% of cases. at least in programming. don't know about the humanities and what not.

Comment: Please don't open multiple questions for the same question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the recurrence relation is obviously

```
 T(0) = 1
 T(1) = T(0) + 1
 T(2) = T(1) + T(0) + 1
 T(n) = T(n/2) + T(n/4) + ... + T(1) + T(0) + 1
        i=n      i=n/2          i=2    i=1   i=0
```

So what is this `T(n)`? Lets concern ourselves with just the powers of 2, for simplicity. Then

```
 T(0) = 1
 T(1) = 2
 T(2) = 4
 T(2^2) = 8
 T(2^3) = 16
 ....
 T(2^k) = 2^k * 2
```

i.e. `T(n) = 2 * n`. So the complexity overall seems to be *O(n)*.

Comment: +1. Just a note to the asker. You also asked it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76937366/5459839), and the answer you got there was wrong (in case you doubt).

Comment: `f(8)` calls `f(4)` when `i=8`, then `i` becomes `4` so `f(2)` is called, then `i=2` and `f(1)` is called. then `i=1` and `f(0)` is called. then `i=0` is considered, the loop ends and the functions ends. I regard this as *O(1)* time operation, hence `T(0) = 1`. thus we get `T(8) = T(4)+T(2)+T(1)+T(0)+1`. the case where `n` is not a power of `2` is not worse than when it is, so it is enough to consider the case `n=2^k` because big-*O* is about *the worst case* performance.

Comment: Is it possible to solve it with recurrence tree method. On level 0 i would have one node, on the level 1 i would have lets say k=logn nodes, which are f(n/2),f(n/4)...f(0), on third level (k-1)+(k-2)+... -> k(k-1)/2  number of nodes  and than my confusion starts i don t know what to do next. I will post one more question soon, with more examples.

Comment: first we write down the equation *without thinking what each T(n) equals to*. then we try to make sense of the equation. That's how it is solved.

Comment: the thing about this kind of analysis is, we don't think about how much time each recursive call takes. all we need to know is that the argument is smaller, and that the call *is* made. that way we get the equation. then we look at the equation, and try to make sense of it. that's the approach that I tried when trying to answer your question.

Comment: Ok, definately  it is O(n) as you already noticed, thank you very much. One more approach wouuld be this T(n)=T(n/2)+T(n/4)+...+T(0), and as T(n/2)=T(n/4)+...+T(0) we get T(n)=2T(n/2) and finally it is O(n).

Comment: and that way we get to use the Master theorem. nice!