# Time complexity harder example 1 (recursion)

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, big-o

This is not my first question on time complexity, I deleted last one because I didn't provide my solution, now that won't be the case. I would say that I know to calculate complexity of loops and basic recursions with Master theorem also I'm familiar with recursion tree but when I have mix of those two there are plenty of problems.

Here are some example. There are  a lot of things i dont know here, so I would appreciate any help.

First example:

```
fun(int n) {
    if (n === 0) { return;}
    console.log(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { fun(n - 1);}
}
```

Here it is obvious that recursion equation is T(n)=nT(n-1)+c and by trying to solve it with substitution T(n-k)=n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-k+1)T(n-k)+c+nc+cn(n-1)+...+cn(n-1)(n-2)...(n-k+1), stops when n=k, so this looks like T(n)=n!T(o)+ c+cn+cn(n-1)+...+c*n!, I dont know with what to approximate this. And how will this change if there is not console.log(n) line. Here chatgpt has 0(2^n),I don't believe in that.It was O(n^n) where I found this originally but without explanation.

What is the right answer? How do we analyze this to get the answer?

Comment: "I deleted last one" - did you?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76938510/time-complexity-of-recursive-function-that-calls-itself-in-a-loop is still available

Comment: That is another thing but i included it here also, i deleted question where was code only. There i didnt provide my process of  trying to solve same examples here.

Comment: @ Лука, you should post one specific question only. here it means you should edit the question, and delete everything except for the one question, e.g. the very first code and the paragraph after it. I'm tempted to make that edit myself and vote to reopen. ... Well, I just did. :)

Comment: This site has rules, and one of them is, one post one question. You can ask a whole lot of them, and maybe get upvotes on each if they are well asked.  Or at least get the +2 reputation bump when you accept an answer. :)

Comment: Thank you, usually all my questions are already asked and answered. It is very very rarely that i have to post question.

Comment: not everything falls under the Master Theorem, some problems we just need to solve ourselves. regarding the code in the question, it can be solved very similarly to the one I answered. it's not `nT(n-1)`, it's again the sum `1+T(0)+T(1)+...+T(n-1)`. try writing it all down following that answer. Instead of `T(2^k) = 2^k` you'll get something like `T(k) = 2^k`. maybe. (?)

Comment: the "second example" in your original question here is the exact replica of the one I already answered. what is still not clear there for you? just trace the execution manually, on paper, for n=0, then n=1, then n=2 etc. step by step.

Comment: see e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=copy%20%22sheet%20of%20paper%22%20user%3a849891&searchOn=3) for more explanations about tracing recursion on paper.

Comment: but why it cant be n*T(n-1)+1  because what ever n is, function will be called n-1 times, plus  print  that is 0(1)

Comment: Oh shikes. I've just now noticed this. I regarded it as if it were `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { fun(i);}`. :( so indeed `T(n)=nT(n-1)` .

Comment: well, empirically, `T(n)=nT(n-1)+c` is O(c\*n!). I just wrote a function that calculates the ratio of the two values for a given `c` and a range of `n`s. Of course you need a language that supports arbitrarily large integers.

Comment: Great! i would say we solved this one

Comment: I haven't worked it out myself, but the equation that you show, `T(n)=n!T(o)+ c+cn+cn(n-1)+...+c*n!` does mean that it is `O(c*n!)` since `T(0) = 1`.